# Where does heroku save repository code?

Tags: git, heroku

Can we see the heroku repository codes in browser(folder and files)like what we see in github?

If it saves in heroku server, is there any way to access those codes and see it in browser as its folder structure?

I am not interested to clone it in my local using command line. I specifically need ability to view and download the code directly like github.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we see the heroku repository codes in browser(folder and files)like what we see in github?

Not that I've ever seen or heard about.  There's really no need for it.

> If it saves in heroku server, is there any way to access those codes and see it in browser as its folder structure?
>
> I am not interested to clone it in my local using command line. I specifically need ability to view and download the code directly like github.

You want the generated zip files offered by GitHub?  I'm 99% sure its not offered by Heroku.

> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app

I really think you need to understand what Git does a bit better.  By cloning the repository you get exactly what you want.  If you don't want to use a CLI -- Use git clone with a git gui application like source tree or tower.

> http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

With that toolset you have the source, and can push to a new remote (like github).

> https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote

Comment: Can the remote repo be accessed without auth? If yes, we can leak secrets easily.